# Is there a recessed floor box for a water supply?

Tags: plumbing

You know how they have those floor boxes that set in concrete with a  flush cover, and when you open it there's electrical outlets inside, but when closed it's flat like the floor and not in the way? (like [this](http://ecatalog.hubbell-wiring.com/press/pdfs/Original_WLBD011.pdf))

Do they make something like that for water? Something that can go in the floor of the garage or utility room with a metal cover on top that can get walked on but not tripped over... but if you want a hose, you can flip the cover up and screw a hose into it?

I'm fairly certain I've seen something like this in a commercial setting before, but have no idea what it's called, and Google is returning garbage as usual. Do they make these? What are they called?

Comment: My Googe search worked type "hose bibb floor box"

Comment: Google only works when you know what something is called. Actually, it looks like "Boxed Ground Hydrants" is the most common term used by manufacturers, which I would never have guessed!

Comment: Ahh yes the name was not exact, but google is smart, I just gave you my first google that returned exactly what you were looking for and nothing extraneous, I did it that way because you stated “google is returning garbage as usual”... I had no problem with the first 4 words I tried.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought for this is a quick connect valve that you normally see in commercial irrigation for remote hose connections.  These are seen outside where a water hose needs to be connected temporarily.  There are two parts - a quick connect valve, and a brass pipe that locks into the valve.  They are sold in the irrigation/automatic sprinkler section of home stores.

[image: Quick connect valve] [image: quick connect key]

*Link to [valve](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-3-4-in-Quick-Coupler-Valve-51029/202206821), Link to [key](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-3-4-in-Quick-Coupler-Key-51031/202206822)*

This could be installed in the floor inside of any kind of standard floor box.  These are cheap, and it has few moving parts so it should be pretty maintenance free.  You can connect the hose to the end of the pipe (key), so you don't have to get down on your hands and knees to screw on a hose.  The quick connect only takes a second (literally) to snap in, and you're ready to use your hose.

If its not clear, you lift the black plastic hood of the valve.  The valve is spring loaded.  The key portion inserts into the valve a few inches and you turn in 90 degrees to lock it in place.

Comment: But what kind of concrete box could be used that would pass inspection? Commercial boxed hydrant boxes are $1000+, and the only other boxes I'm finding are for electrical. Is it code complaint to use electrical floor boxes with RNC, and water lines inside the RNC? Or maybe all we need is to put PVC under the concrete and later we can run a garden hose through it or possibly pex? the idea is to have water available in the middle of the room without creating a tripping hazard with a hose across the floor..

Answer (score 0):

Concrete street water meter box. Ask at your local water utility.